# How to prove this statement using Divisibility of Integer Combination (DIC)?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, solution-verification, divisibility

For all integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ if $a \mid (xb+ yc)$ for all integers $x$ and $y$, then $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$.

How would I prove this using DIC?

Comment: Let $x=1,y=0$, and vice versa...

Comment: How'd I let that fly over my head, thank you.